# What is English equivalent for Russian "я хочу" in the meaning "я хочу посмотреть их сегодня вечером"?

Tags: phrase-request, translation, answers

The context is:

> Have you looked my links?
>   я хочу (я хочу посмотреть их сегодня вечером).

Is it possible to use short answer? (i want, i wish)

and also is it possible to say "i will" in some cases.

Comment: I’m afraid, despite the tag being existent, we are not a translation website: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/translation-questions

Comment: Why is "I want to see you tonight" not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for short answer. Is it possible the short (неполный) answer or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to the question

> Have you looked at my links (the links I sent you)?

you can answer

> I will.

but that's a bit brusque, and it'd be a little more appropriate, I believe in Russian as well, and any language for that matter, to say

> - No, but I will.
> - No. I will, though.
> - No, I haven't, but I will.
> - No, I'm going to do it tonight.

The last one would be used if you had decided this when the conversation took place, and you just clarified it then.

Maybe even apologize, like this:

> Sorry, I haven't, but I will.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! unfortunately i can't voteup because my reputation is only 1.